# Is double spending with electrum still possible?

Tags: electrum, doublespend

I tried to follow this tutorial, but I kept on getting an error message saying that there was a mempool conflict and that it was rejected by the network.I even used a script so that the mouse clicked the send button at the same time.

[Understanding a Bitcoin Double Spending Transaction by Performing one on yourself](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50375/understanding-a-bitcoin-double-spending-transaction-by-performing-one-on-yoursel/54211?noredirect=1#comment62969_54211)

Can anyone help or share their experiences?